# Is there a simplified chart of how many amps can I get at a distance by wire gauge?

Tags: electrical

I'm looking for a simplified chart of max amperage based off wire type and distance.  Something like this:

```
                          50ft  75ft  100ft 150ft  200ft  250ft  300ft
NM-B 12 Gauge             20Amp 20Amp 20Amp  ??     ??     ??     ??
Extension Cord 14 Gauge   15Amp 12Amp 8Amp   ??     ??     ??     ??
```

I'm pretty sure that things are more complex than this, but this isn't a high end job, it's a temporary fix to a much bigger problem.  I just need some way to figure out what *can* be done.

Comment: It's much more complex than that, and there are no flat numbers for certain sizes. Multiple factors are involved such as actual and calculated load, ambient temperature, etc. There are several good online voltage drop calculators where you just punch in your parameters and you get all the info you need.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how helpful it is, but here's a chart that shows voltage drop at various distances. This chart shows the voltage drop across copper conductors, at 100% the allowable circuit capacity.

[image]

This chart that shows the voltage drop across copper conductors, with a 15 ampere load on the circuit.

[image]

And one with a 20 ampere load.

[image]

If you want to do the calculations yourself, you can use the formula:

`Voltage Drop = 2 * Length * Current * Resistance`

That will give you a rough approximation of the voltage drop that should be expected.

<sup>*You can look up the resistance of the conductors through the manufacturer, or use values found in the National Electrical Code.</sup>

Comment: I have a set of voltage drop charts similar to these when I put together a "cookbook"  while training new designers. The biggest problem with voltage drop is that you must know the power useage (amperage, KW, or HP). Once you know how much power you are actually going to use then you can apply the formula. If you don't know, then the designer must use 16A for #12 and 12A for #14 (80% of the capacity of the overload protection).

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician I like to use 100% of circuit capacity for voltage drop calculations, as that gives the "worst case" voltage drop.  Using 80% of full circuit capacity for voltage drop calculations, means your lights are going to dim when your fridge turns on.  80% is fine for continuous loads when doing load calculations, but not so good for voltage drop estimates.

Comment: This would be a great discussion for a blog.

Answer (score 1):

I use this simple voltage drop [calculator](http://www.southwire.com/support/voltage-drop-calculator.htm).  As far as extension cords they have different ampacities than standard wiring methods but this calculator will provide the voltage drop all you need to enter is the voltage, length, type & size wire of wire, location, and the current draw. 3% is the max voltage drop that should be used for the calculation.